# Не работает рабочий стол после установки CUDA

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia

Я установил CUDA командой `sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` но после перезапуска не работает рабочий стол. Сначала не запускался а после попросило ввойти. Рабочий стол загрузился но ничего не работает, даже курсор не реагировал, а потом исчез. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Видимо вы сломали видеодрайвер. Какая версия драйвера стояла до установки, какая после установки, какая модель видеокарты?

Comment: Nvidia RTX 2060. Сейчас стоит 510.47.03, не знаю какая до

Comment: Тогда не знаю, на такой достаточно новой видеокарте драйвер сломатья не должен был. Если вдруг у вас случайно установлен `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, попробуйте удалить его, ну и для верности явно установите `nvidia-driver-510` на всякий случай (вдруг какие-то недостающие файлы подтянет)

Comment: Спасибо. Я решил проблему в тупую apt-get perge nvidia-*, и потом востоновил настройки

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему довольно примитивно, но это может помочь кому-то.

Заходим в Recovery Mode *(ESC, или Shift+Alt+F1)* во время загрузки системы.
Далее нужно выбрать терминал с правами root и написать пароль от рута.

Удаляем сломанные дрова командой:

```
apt-get perge nvidia-*
```

Далее вводим команду:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Перезагрузка системы и все должно войти без CUDA